# How can you find duplicate rows and delete output based on whether or not one column has a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with data like:

```
job1,job_type,new
job1,job_type,cancel
job2,job_type,new
job3,job_type,complete
```

I need to eliminate job1 because it was cancelled.  How might I go about doing that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try researching on how to solve this problem, use this site and others online as a resource. Break the task down into steps, and then go from there: 1. how to read csv with pandas (i see that you have the tag added). 2. how to delete rows where a column has a certain value (value being "cancel" here). 3. How to write csv with pandas. If you get stuck while building a solution, then feel free to ask.

Comment: I do not simply want to remove the row that says cancel though, I want to remove both the new and cancel row.

Comment: Literally everything i said still stands. Make an attempt first. *Show us* what you've tried so far.

Comment: do you want to simply sear/replace directly on the file ?
Perhaps you want to load that file then process data then save it again... to search replace the file you might as well do it with sed or perl lol

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from io import StringIO

csvfile = StringIO("""job1,job_type,new
job1,job_type,cancel
job2,job_type,new
job3,job_type,complete""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, header=None)

df[~df[0].isin(df.loc[df[2] == 'cancel',0])].to_csv('out.csv', index=False, header=None)

!more out.csv
```

Output:

```
job2,job_type,new
job3,job_type,complete
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with set function in python.
Convert each column or row into a list and do set operation to that list.

Ex:

```
A = ["a","b", "a" ]
Dub = list(set(A))
print(Dub)
```

Output:

```
["a", "b"]
```